# How do I use aggregate to do group in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Please review the sample JSON data.

```
{  Id: 2, Type: 4, platform: 3 }
{  Id: 1, Type: 3, platform: 1 }
{  Id: 1, Type: 2, platform: 3 }
{  Id: 1, Type: 3, platform: 3 }
```

I want to group by Id first, Then group by platform
like this Or better presentation easy to use:

```
{ 
  '1': {              // id
        '1': {        // platform
              '3':1   // Type : Type's count
             },
        '3': {        // platform
              '2':1,
              '3':1
             }
       }
}
```

I use mongoDB 3.6, Is this possible?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with `v3.6`.

**Reason:** To transform into `key:value` [where `key` must be `String`] object, we need to use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) operator.

As a `platform`, `Type`, `Id` are `Numeric` values, we cannot transform into `key:value` structure, since [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/index.html) is available since `v4.0`.

**Workaround:** We can create array with literal equivalent to the `platform`, `Type` and `Id` values. Or, we can use [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/index.html) operator to define manually how to transform numbers into equivalent literal value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      converter: ["0","1","2","3","4","5"] // add here items equivalent to numbers 
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        Id: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$converter","$Id"]
        },
        Type: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$converter","$Type"]
        },
        platform: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$converter","$platform"]
        }
      },
      "count": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        Id: "$_id.Id",
        Type: "$_id.Type"
      },
      "data": {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.platform",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.Id",
      "data": {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.Type",
          v: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "data": {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lRmBadLb7rZ)